# How to vary modal content (without bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have a bunch of contents that all trigger the same modal. There another way to varying modal without repeat the same code in HTML?

I tried use event.relatedTarget, but without sucess.

Also, the modal is trigger by another div with id *modalBtn*.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modalSpeaker');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```
    <div id="modalSpeaker" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-info">
                    <img src="images/speakers/speaker01.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>About 01</span>
                    <span>About 02</span>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-about">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam amet consequatur, asperiores blanditiis quis nobis quaerat non aperiam doloribus quae, voluptatibus fuga voluptate porro dolorum velit eaque fugiat autem. Aut.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi animi non odit eaque, tempora et fugit vitae officia similique quidem, officiis quisquam esse ipsa enim numquam distinctio sapiente nostrum ratione.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use display to none for the other part you didn't want to show among your needs

Comment: Where is the element with `id = "'modalBtn'"`

Comment: @MrJ I do not want to repeat multiple lines of HTML code.

Comment: @MaheerAli In another div that trigger the modal.

Comment: @jungenWerters I din't say that this is just for your différents parts of modal code  INSIDE the unique Modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a proxy method or a lambda expression (or anonymous function) for your event listener, and pass arguments to your modal display function in order to vary the content in the modal elements.

When you register a function as the callback for an [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener), you must provide the function reference, but not call it directly. This is because, the `EventListener` will call the function once the actual event has been fired. This limits your options as far as variability goes on invoking your callback function.

If instead of passing a function reference, you pass a lambda expression, then you can invoke anything you want inside the lambda expression, and this will only be executed once the lambda is invoked when the event is fired.

This gives you the flexibility to define methods with complex argument signatures that can be executed as the result of an event being fired, but with different arguments being passed for each unique event.

There are several other ways to do this as well, but I see this as the cleanest way to accomplish your task.

The below example shows how this can be done:

```js
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
const title = document.querySelector('#modal .title');

function openModal(color) {
  title.innerText = `Selected color: ${color}`;
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById('modal-close').addEventListener('click', closeModal);

const buttonG = document.getElementById('g-btn');
const buttonR = document.getElementById('r-btn');
const buttonB = document.getElementById('b-btn');

buttonG.addEventListener('click', () => openModal('Green'));
buttonR.addEventListener('click', () => openModal('Red'));
buttonB.addEventListener('click', () => openModal('Blue'));
```

```css
div#modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span class="title">Click one of the buttons to see the effect...</span>
</div>

<div id="modal">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <button type="button" id="modal-close">Close</button>
</div>

<button id="g-btn" type="button">Green</button>
<button id="r-btn" type="button">Red</button>
<button id="b-btn" type="button">Blue</button>
```

Comment: It's worked! Also, you can explain more about why you choise proxy method and lambda expression for resolve this problem? Thank you!